# Check if element exists in tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples that look like :

```
CODES = (
    ('apple', 'reddelicious'),
    ('caramel', 'sweetsticky'),
    ('banana', 'yellowfruit'),
)
```

What's the best way to check if a value exists in that tuple? For example I want to be able to say:

```
'apple' in CODES
```

and get True

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You are looking for [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any('apple' in code for code in CODES):
    ...
```

Combined with a simple [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), this does the task. The generator expression takes each tuple and yields `True` if it is contains `'apple'`. `any()` then returns `True` when the first item it requests returns `True` (otherwise, `False`). Hence this does what you want. It also reads nicely - *if any of the tuples contain `'apple'`*.

If you are doing this a massive number of times and need performance, then it might be worth making a set of all of the values to allow you to do this very quickly:

```
cache = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(CODES)))
```

Naturally, constructing this will be slow and use memory, so it wouldn't be a good idea unless you need a lot of performance and will be doing a lot of membership checks.

Comment: what if instead of just checking for the existence - i wanted to get the second value? In this case "reddelicious"?

Comment: In that case, you are using the wrong data structure, use a `dict`, then just do `CODES["apple"]` (and catch the `KeyError` if it isn't there).

Comment: @9-bits just use `dic=dict(CODES)`, this will return a dictionary.And then `dic['apple']` will result in `'reddelicious'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Well, if the data exists in this format, then yes, but if you are making a literal as in your example, no need to take the extra step, just make a `dict` to begin with.

Comment: For those of you still living in Py2.x https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any ```any()``` is there too!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

Using it with `in` will result in short-circuiting, similar to `any()`.

```
In [30]: CODES = (
   ....:     ('apple', 'reddelicious'),
   ....:     ('caramel', 'sweetsticky'),
   ....:     ('banana', 'yellowfruit'),
   ....: )


In [31]: from itertools import chain

In [32]: 'apple' in chain(*CODES)
Out[32]: True

In [33]: 'foo' in chain(*CODES)
Out[33]: False
```

---

For **performance comparisons** you can check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902359/best-way-to-check-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-list-of-lists).

Comment: +1, This is a reasonable way to do this - I'm not sure how it compares performance-wise. Although you should use `chain.from_iterable()` over `chain(*)`.

Comment: @Lattyware I think as both `any()` and my method are doing short-circuiting, so, the performance difference should be negligible for large data.