# Python IF Statement Not Correctly Identifying Value

Tags: python

I know ultimately this has to be a formatting issue, but can't get quite figure it out.  Here is an example of what my list looks like:

```
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], ['e1', 'e2']]
```

My code with IF statement looks like this:

```
guesses = 0
    while guesses < 5:
        guess = input("Guess a spot on the grid (example A10:")
        guesses + 1
        if guess in grid1.board:
            print("Sweet nice hit!")
        else:
            print("sorry try again")
```

Every entry that seemingly should be correct is giving me a "sorry try again" error.  Any idea what my issue might be?

EDIT ADDED MORE CODE HERE---this is where i run the game (battleship)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    grid = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
    player1 = Player()
    player2 = Player()
    grid1 = Board(grid)
    grid2 = Board(grid)
    grid1.print_board()
    chris =[]

    for ship_name, ship_size in SHIP_INFO:
        ship1 = Ship(player1,ship_name,ship_size,grid1) #create ship instance
        # ask_coords = ship1.ask_ship_coords(ship_name) #ask user for starting coordinate for ship in form "A1"
        x,y = ship1.split_coordinates(ship_name) #split coordinate from above into x, y variables and check if valid
        direction = ship1.ask_ship_location() # ask for ship's postion --horizontal or vertical
        created_coords = ship1.create_ship_coordinates(x, y, ship_size, direction,grid) # create all coordinates for ship based on size of ship and locatio
        #add coordinates to player's grid
        grid1.board.append(created_coords)

        grid1.print_ship_coordinates(created_coords, direction,grid) #loop through coords for ship to print out on displayed grid
```

and top of my Board class:

```
BOARD_SIZE = 10

class Board:
    board = []

    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.grid = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
```

Comment: Can you show your `grid1.board`?

Comment: The indentation seems broken. What is `grid1.board`?

Comment: I think "my list" is the same as `grid1.board`. I don't see any other mention of a list.

Comment: Python doesn't check the sublists for an item when it searches the list. Since `guess` will never be one of the sublists (it is always a string), the `if` will never be evaluated as True.

Comment: yes that grid1.board is the list that i posted at top of this post ...i posted some other code...it's an instance calling a Board class

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1156087/5827958

Comment: `[['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]` this will probably cause problems because each of the elements in those lists all point to the same thing. Try e.g. `L = [ [6, 7] ]*5; L[0].append(8); L`

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26167566/5827958

Comment: This one looks different, but it is actually quite similar and has a lot of highly upvoted answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843158/5827958

Comment: @zondo thanks! seems to be exactly what's going on here